# DateTime with Timezone in php and Microsoft Graph API

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm trying to read the calendar entries of rooms and output the next three events on their calendar. However I am testing first to see if I can get just the first 3 events of the day, but it seems the timezone or something else is causing it to not show events correctly.

This is a function I wrote:

```
function mb_get_meetings($mb_email = null, $mb_proxy = false, $mb_datetime_start = null, $mb_datetime_finish = null)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');

    // get the Microsoft Open Graph API
    $mb_msgraph        = json_decode(mb_microsoft_opengraph($mb_proxy), true); // custom function to get Beaker Token + $mb_proxy for internal proxy on or off for dev testing
    $mb_msgraph_token    = $mb_msgraph['access_token'];

    $mb_datetimenow    = new DateTime();
    $mb_datetimezone    = new DateTimeZone('Australia/Melbourne');
    $mb_datetimenow->setTimezone($mb_datetimezone);

    $mb_datetime_start    = new DateTime($mb_datetime_start, $mb_datetimezone);
    $mb_datetime_finish = new DateTime($mb_datetime_finish, $mb_datetimezone);

    $mb_datetime_start    = $mb_datetime_start->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u');
    $mb_datetime_finish = $mb_datetime_finish->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u');

    $mb_url_string = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' . $mb_email . '/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime=' . $mb_datetime_start . '&endDateTime=' . $mb_datetime_finish;

    $mb_args = array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Authorization'    => 'Bearer ' . $mb_msgraph_token,
            'Content-Type'    => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
            'Prefer'        => 'outlook.timezone="Australia/Melbourne"'
        ),
        'httpversion'    => '1.1'
    );
    $mb_output    = wp_remote_get($mb_url_string, $mb_args);
    $mb_output    = wp_remote_retrieve_body($mb_output);
    return $mb_output;
}
```

I am using Wordpress as the backend and it does retrieve the body.

In my frontend page I call:

```
$mbroom = (mb_get_meetings('email@domain.tld', true, 'today 7am', 'today 7pm'));
$mbroom = json_decode($mbroom, true);
$mbroom = $mbroom['value'];


foreach ($mbroom as $k => $v) {

    // get the first 3 entries
    if ($k < 3) {

        print_r($k);
        print_r($v['subject']);
        print_r(date('g:i', strtotime($v['start']['dateTime']));
        print_r(date('g:i', strtotime($v['end']['dateTime']));
        print_r($v['organizer']['emailAddress']['name']);

        echo '<hr>';
    }
}
```

In the results, I will get sometimes no calendar entries while other times I might get entries for 2pm but not anything from 8am. I have tried changing it to hardcoded `YYYY-MM-DDD 08:00` and `YYYY-MM-DD 20:00` but to no avail. I have also tried `yesterday` and `tomorrow` but none/incorrect results.

I also tried booking an entire day with 30-minute meetings and that too wasn't working.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do some debugging.  What does that fully constructed url end up looking like?  Since you just concatenate the dates, the format is probably not what the graph API expects.

Comment: Can you try using `->format('c') ` instead of `->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest sending the startDateTime and endDateTime parameters in UTC, formatted as ISO 8601 as described in the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), which you have done. However, I'd suggest using a PHP constant, since it's less error-prone (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.iso8601). Doing something like the following for those parameters:

```php
 $startDateTime = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
 $startDateTime = $startDateTime->format(DATE_ISO8601);
 $startDateTime = substr($startDateTime, 0, strpos($startDateTime, '+'));
```

Edit:
Using substring to remove the locale part of the DateTime string was probably a naïve thing to do, but it does serve the purpose.